# transform returning null pointer exception but the parameters arent null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, kml, transformer-model

I'm generating a KML file and at the point where I use the transformer API, I get the NullPointerException exception. Here's the code I'm refering too:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(kml);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("src/mapa/mapa.kml"));
            System.out.print("DESPRES DE CREAR RESULT\n");
            if(source == null)
                System.out.print("SOURCE IS NULL");
            if(result == null)
                System.out.print("RESULT IS NULL");
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            System.out.print("AFTER TRASNFORM\n");
```

It doesn't print any of the NULL System.outs, however it doesn't print the last one either. Why is it giving me NPE?

Exception:

```
DESPRES DE CREAR RESULT
ERROR:  ''
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at Joc.crearMapa(Joc.java:199)
    at MastersOfWar.main(MastersOfWar.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
---------
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at Joc.crearMapa(Joc.java:199)
    at MastersOfWar.main(MastersOfWar.java:18)
```

Comment: that means `transformer` is null! which should not be the case, can you paste exception trace?

Comment: `transformerFactory.newTransformer(<source is missing here>)`

Comment: chack this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer(javax.xml.transform.Source)

Comment: What am I supposed to type in there? All the examples I've read didn't send parameters to this constructor

Comment: check this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html

Comment: read about that more and you will understand, it has to be xml source for transformation

Comment: Okay thanks hopefully I get it fixed

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code

```
System.out.print(transformerFactory.newTransformer());
```

It probably returns null, making your transformer object null.

Comment: It doesn't. It returns this: `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl@7d4991ad`